# Configure SNMP to send messages to two different monitoring platforms

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, monitoring, snmp

Is it possible to configure snmpd on Ubuntu (via snmpd.conf) to send messages to two different monitoring applications?   For example, lets say I have defined a read only community called 'readonly', is it possible to configure snmpd.conf to communicate with two different platforms (let's say 10.1.1.10 and 10.1.1.20 are the IP addresses) like this

`rocommunity readonly 10.1.1.10`

`rocommunity readonly 10.1.1.20`

I cannot seem to find any examples on the internet of a configuration that is sending SNMP messages to two separate platforms, so I figured i'd ask here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are using traps to flag significant events, SNMP will not send data to either server.  You can configure multiple communities that can query the data.  In your case both clients would be able to query with the same credentials.

Newer versions of SNMP have better security.  You may want to use different access configurations for the two monitoring clients.  This may include restricting which data each client can read.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to publish your community using the netmask instead:

```
rocommunity readonly 10.1.1.0/24
```

But your way should work too, can't check it myself at the moment.

Comment: Good to know, but this does seem like it would be a greater security risk since it would give an attacker the ability to query snmp from any point on the network.  Currently we have snmp configured to only be queried from the snmp management station, and I think that's how it should be for now.  Regardless, still good info to have.  Thanks